# Excecuting some JavaScript code makes Android web application hang

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am developing Android web application by using PhoneGap, it works well at most part, but sometime when I want to download or upload files, the application hang up and does not respond to any touch event till the task is finished. I am going to describe more about code I have written;

HTML code:

```
<a id="download">Download/a>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$("#download").click(function() {
    /*Here I used a plugin which is a Java class, and call this plugin and pass the      required parameters*/
    var data = [id, fileName];
    window.download(callServiceSuccessCallBack,
            callServiceFailCallBack, "download", data);
});
```

The XML config file which register the plugin here:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin name="DowloadFilePlugin" value="com.example.plugin.DowloadFilePlugin" />
</plugins>
```

Java code:

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
    CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
   if ("download".equals(action)) {
       // do something
   }
   return true;
}
```

When I press the button then the application hanged till the file downloaded.
If anyone knows about this problem please let me know how to solve, in addition i also tried `window.setTimeout(code, 0);` did not solve the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by adding thread in JAVA code as below:

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if ("beep".equals(action)) {
        final long duration = args.getLong(0);
        cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // do something....
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a setTimeout with a delay of 0 or 100ms to start your action :

```
$("#download").click(function() {
    /*Here I used a plugin which is a Java class, and call this plugin and pass the      required parameters*/
    var data = [id, fileName];
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.download(callServiceSuccessCallBack,
            callServiceFailCallBack, "download", data);
    },0);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I before tried setTimeout(code, 0); but this cannot solve UI hanging problem